# Unable to register the C# dll as a COM Component, The module was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found

Tags: c#, .net, com, regsvr32

I have created a class and made it com visible:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("FD909333-3CD0-477F-8A7E-B8045B0B84EC")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("TestComApp.TestApp.TestClass")]
    public class TestClass:ITestCom
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
    }
```

Also the interface is set to be COM visible:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("26567B41-15DB-4EE2-A277-357EAE96BF6A")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    interface ITestCom
    {
         int Add(int a, int b);
    }
```

But when I am trying to register the DLL

```
regsvr32 /i TestComApp.dll
```

I am getting the following error "The module was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found"

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To register a .NET DLL, you need to use Regasm.exe instead of regsvr32.exe. Regasm.exe is located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (or similar depending on .NET version).

Also make sure to specify the /codebase option, or make the assembly strongly-named, otherwise COM won't be able to find the DLL.